# Unable to open Few .jar files in Ubuntu 15.04, Error: "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar "

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, java, jar

I got stuck with this, I can't able to open few `.jar` files. Its throwing error as:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

Please check the screenshot(1 pic is of BurpLoader.jar unable to open, 1 one is burpsuite n was able to open it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove annoying environment variable JAVA\_TOOL\_OPTIONS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/650548/remove-annoying-environment-variable-java-tool-options)

Answer (score -1):

Have you try using 7zip, and type this in the terminal:

First install 7zip an unrar:

```
 sudo apt-get install 7zip unrar
```

and then type this in the terminal:

```
 unzip (file to extract) -d (path)
```

Comment: Sorry, what? Why is this helpful?